# Analyze Jmeter aggregate report when generated in non-gui mode

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

In the GUI mode, Aggregate report shows a column name called `'Throughput'`. I have generated the aggregate report in non-GUI mode:

The columns in the csv file are:
sampler_label
aggregate_report_count
average aggregate_report_median 
aggregate_report_90%_line
aggregate_report_min
aggregate_report_max
aggregate_report_error% 
aggregate_report_rate
aggregate_report_bandwidth
aggregate_report_stddev

I do not understand which one corresponds to `'Throughput'` in this.

The command I used to generate this aggregate report is:

```
sudo java -jar /home/jmeter_rnr/apache-jmeter-2.13/lib/ext/CMDRunner.jar --tool Reporter --generate-csv  /home/jmeter_rnr/apache-jmeter-2.13/agg_report_50xuser.csv --input-jtl /home/jmeter_rnr/apache-jmeter-2.13/output_50x.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jmeter 2.13v which give the Through put directly in aggregate report.